# Does a ninja have to be a Jōnin to be a Kage?

Tags: naruto

I mean does a ninja have to go through the ranks of being a Genin, a Chūnin, a Jōnin and then finally a Kage?

In the movie **Road to Ninja** Naruto asks Iruka to fill his Jōnin  form but Iruka refuses it saying that Naruto will have to be a Chūnin to fill out the application form of Jōnin. But when Naruto became Hokage he still has to be a Genin right? If thats a case can any of the a Genin, a Chūnin, a Jōnin become a Kage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Naruto's case, it might be **possible**. Hokage is praised to be the strongest shinobi in the village, while strong shinobi is capable of passing Chuunin/Jounin exam. Naruto has only participated in the Chuunin exam twice throughout the whole series. One is during the Chunin Exams Arc, and the other one is in the [5th OVA of Naruto Shippuden](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Ch%C5%ABnin_Exam_on_Fire!_Naruto_vs._Konohamaru!). He failed both exams anyways. Nevertheless, he's still strong, but his silliness made him failed the 2nd exam. Shinobi rank might not be the most important fact to consider when electing a new Hokage, they need to be loyal and trustworthy, as Naruto has all of it.

Comment: Note also that at the end of the aforementioned OVA, his friends said that Naruto don't have to take Chuunin exam as they all recognized his strength.

Comment: as well, its entirely possible that he went and attained those ranks in the approximatly 13 years kakashi was Hokage.

Comment: @Ryan can't imagine the face of the other exam participants. Remember how they looked when he participated in Chuunin exam after he defeated Pain. Now that he have defeated an even greater adversary...